# Which string constructor is invoked?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, stdstring, string-literals

I know this is initialization but I am confused which of the 2 constructors is invoked when a string literal is used in each case. Are they both copy constructors?

```
string::string(const string& strString)
string::string(const char *szCString)
```

**Case1:**

```
string sSource("my string");
```

**Case2:**

```
const char *szSource("my string");
```

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Comment: You can put some print statement in them and see for yourself. Or run it with debugger.

Comment: Just run it in the debugger already. Then step through the code and see for yourself - *or* get a copy of the standard and read the rules.

Comment: It wasn't a "remark", it was a fairly simple question. What is the answer? You have to show evidence of research and thought before you get help. We're not your servants!

Comment: @softwarelover _"Are they both copy constructors?"_ A copy constructor needs to take the same (or derivate) type as input. So ask yourself: _Is `std::string` derived from `const char*`?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [check what the compiler does](https://godbolt.org/z/zJWtfu) (GodBolt.org):

For the first case, the constructor which gets called is:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<std::allocator<char> >(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
```

or, in other words and if we ignore the default value for the allocator reference parameter, it's:

```
std::string::string(char const*)
```

As for the second case, no string constructor is called. You only get:

```
    mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
```

which puts a pointer to the location of the raw characters.

Now, what I think you were confused about is the semantics of string literals. **String literals are *not* `std::string`s**! Remember that C++ as a language does *not* have an inherent string type; `std::string` is from the standard library.

So what *is* the type of string literals? It's a char array. [See for yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4f9e61461392ca5) (Coliru.com; the example has code for obtaining type names as strings)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I wish people avoid remarks and answer like you did.

Comment: softwarelover: That's not fair. It's important that you learn how to investigate these questions _yourself_ rather than have answers spoon-fed to you. @LightnessRacesinOrbit was trying to help by engaging you in a (mini) conversation.

Comment: It was not really spoon-fed. I am aware of copy constructors, move constructors, and all that... it is just that regular constructors and copy constructors made me confused about strings. I was thinking about C-style strings as part of C++..

Comment: @softwarelover: What you're not aware of is how to appropriately ask questions here on the site, which means - showing how you've tried to obtain the answer yourself, or why you're having a dilemma you can't resolve yourself.